# @ModelAttribute from jquery ajax form is null

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form that I am using to submit via ajax to a spring action that is not populating the @ModelAttribute properly.  I have tried the inputs as siteName site.siteName, and other various things.

For my form, I'm doing $('form').ajaxForm() and then it submits via AJAX when I click the submit button.

I see the data being passed via firebug, but Spring is not doing anything with it.
Any ideas why it's always null?

My Site class:

```
public class Site implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String siteName;

    public Site() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        // noop
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSiteName() {
        return this.siteName;
    }

    public void setSiteName(String siteName) {
        this.siteName = siteName;
    }

}
```

My HTML (loaded from ajax)

```
<form method='post' action='/web/admin/sites/new'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Site</legend>
        <label for='site.siteName'>Site Name</label> <input type='text' id='site.siteName' name='site.siteName'/> 
            <input type='hidden' name='site.id' value=''/>
            <input type='submit'value='Save' />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My alternate HTML (loaded via ajax)

```
<form method='post' action='/web/admin/sites/new'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Site</legend>
        <label for='siteName'>Site Name</label> <input type='text' id='siteName' name='siteName'/> 
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value=''/>
            <input type='submit'value='Save' />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Finally, my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSite(@ModelAttribute Site site, Model m)
{
    /*Site s = new Site();*/
    log.debug("Saving site from POST: {}", site.toString());
    m.addAttribute("site", site);
    return "/admin/sites/new_site";
}
```

And finally the output from the log statement:

> ... SitesController - Saving site from POST: Site [id=null,
>   siteName=null]

Comment: Instead of `site.something`, just use `something`.

Comment: I've already tried that, as my comment says I've tried about every variation I can think of.

Comment: can u share ur controller method wer u have set the model attribute for Site to load ur ajax form?

Comment: What version of Spring MVC are you using? Your last HTML snippet and controller work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Spring tags*** combine with ***HTML tags*** you just need to change your JSP as follows

***JSP FILE***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" action='/web/admin/sites/new' commandName="mySite">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Site</legend>
        <label for='site.siteName'>Site Name</label> 
            <form:input  path='siteName'/> 
            <form:hidden path='id' />
            <form:input type='submit'value='Save' />
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSite(@ModelAttribute("mySite") Site site, Model m) {
    log.debug("Saving site from POST: {}", site.toString());
    m.addAttribute("site", site);
    return "/admin/sites/new_site";
}
```

***NOTE:*** *add the mySite object in module before redirecting to site.jsp as*

```
Site site = new Site();
model.addAttribute("mySite", site);
//here we send request to site.jsp page.
return "site";
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

When using @ModelAttribute, make sure you use the 'modelAttribute' attribute in your jsp page. Shown below -

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="site" action="/web/admin/sites/new">
     <form:input path="siteName" />
</form:form>
```

This will make sure that siteName property is populated in 'Site' model.

Comment: This is only necessary if they were using the `<form:input>` element.